# How can I apply "ClearContents" to a large number of cells and ranges?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code. It doesn't work. Says, "1004 Error", when implemented.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Unload Me
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Set Exams-Answers").Range("F21, H23:H26, F31, H33:H36, F41, 
H43:H46, F51, H53:H56, F61, H63:H66, F71, H73:H76, F81, H83:H86, F91, H93:H96, F101, 
H103:H106, F111, H113:H116, F121, H123:H126, F131, H133:H136, F141, H143:H146, F151, 
H153:H156, F161, H163:H166, F171, H173:H176, F181, H183:H186, F191, H193:H196, F201, 
H203:H206, F211, H213:H216, F221, H223:H226, F231, H233:H236, F241, H243:H246, F251, 
H253:H256, F261, H263:H266, P21, R23:R26, P31, R33:R36, P41, R43:R46, P51, R53:R56, 
P61, R63:R66, P71, R73:R76, P81, R83:R86, P91, R93:R96, P101, R103:R106, P111, 
R113:R116, P121, R123:R126, P131, R133:R136, P141, R143:R146, P151, R153:R156, P161, 
R163:R166, P171, R173:R176, P181, R183:R186, P191, R193:R196, P201, R203:R206, P211, 
R213:R216, P221, R223:R226, P231, R233:R236, P241, R243:R246, P251, R253:R256, P261, 
R263:R266").ClearContents 'Clear cell contents
SetQuestions1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: The string (defining the range) is too long for this to work. One way is to split it into multiple ranges and clearing each range like `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Set Exams-Answers").Range("F21, H23:H26, F31, H33:H36, F41").ClearContents`. Another way is to give this range a name (withing excel) such as "AnswersRange" and in you vba simply use `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Set Exams-Answers").Range("AnswersRange").ClearContents`

Comment: Super Symmetry: You are right!  I obviously exceeded the range limit, hence the error. Your insight was really very helpful. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is technically correct, but hitting some internal restrictions of vba. your region-select is simply selecting to many regions or too long, causing internal errors.

got exactly the same error on a empty sheet, fixed it by breaking up the select-string:

```
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Set Exams-Answers").Range("F21, H23:H26, F31, H33:H36, F41,H43:H46, F51, H53:H56, F61, H63:H66, F71, H73:H76, F81, H83:H86, F91, H93:H96, F101,H103:H106, F111, H113:H116, F121, H123:H126, F131, H133:H136, F141, H143:H146, F151,H153:H156").ClearContents
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Set Exams-Answers").Range("F161, H163:H166, F171, H173:H176, F181, H183:H186, F191, H193:H196, F201,H203:H206, F211, H213:H216, F221, H223:H226, F231, H233:H236, F241, H243:H246, F251,H253:H256, F261, H263:H266, P21, R23:R26, P31, R33:R36").ClearContents
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Set Exams-Answers").Range("P41, R43:R46, P51, R53:R56,P61, R63:R66, P71, R73:R76, P81, R83:R86, P91, R93:R96, P101, R103:R106, P111,R113:R116, P121, R123:R126, P131, R133:R136, P141, R143:R146, P151, R153:R156, P161,R163:R166, P171").ClearContents
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Set Exams-Answers").Range("R173:R176, P181, R183:R186, P191, R193:R196, P201, R203:R206, P211,R213:R216, P221, R223:R226, P231, R233:R236, P241, R243:R246, P251, R253:R256, P261,R263: R266 ").ClearContents
```

Comment: You are right! I obviously exceeded the range limit, hence the error. Your insight was really very helpful. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

VBA maximum allowed string length, to be manipulated in such a case, is 256.

I prepared function able to split such a string in portions less or equal to 256. It will return an array and base on its elements, a range is built using `Union` and the contents will be cleared at once. Please, test the next code:

```
Sub testClearContentxBySplitString256()
 Dim x As String, arr As Variant, rng As Range, El As Variant
  x = "F21, H23:H26, F31, H33:H36, F41, H43:H46, F51, H53:H56, F61, H63:H66, F71, H73:H76, F81, H83:H86, F91, H93:H96, F101, H103:H106, F111, H113:H116, F121, H123:H126, F131, H133:H136, F141, H143:H146, F151, H153:H156, F161, H163:H166, F171, H173:H176, F181, H183:H186, F191, H193:H196, F201, H203:H206, F211, H213:H216, F221, H223:H226, F231, H233:H236, F241, H243:H246, F251, H253:H256, F261, H263:H266, P21, R23:R26, P31, R33:R36, P41, R43:R46, P51, R53:R56, P61, R63:R66, P71, R73:R76, P81, R83:R86, P91, R93:R96, P101, R103:R106, P111, R113:R116, P121, R123:R126, P131, R133:R136, P141, R143:R146, P151, R153:R156, P161, R163:R166, P171, R173:R176, P181, R183:R186, P191, R193:R196, P201, R203:R206, P211, R213:R216, P221, R223:R226, P231, R233:R236, P241, R243:R246, P251, R253:R256, P261, R263:R266"
  arr = split256(x)
  If Not IsArray(arr) Then
     Set rng = Range(arr)
  Else
    For Each El In arr
      If rng Is Nothing Then
        Set rng = Range(El)
      Else
        Set rng = Union(rng, Range(El))
      End If
    Next
  End If
  rng.Select 'only fir visual efect. You can comment/delete the line after seeing the selected non contiguous range...
  rng.ClearContents
End Sub
```

and function splitting the string:

```
Function split256(strSplit As String) As Variant
    Dim arr As Variant, i As Long, strInterm As String
    Dim strRest As String, k As Long, boolLast As Boolean
    If Len(strSplit) <= 256 Then
        split256 = strSplit: Exit Function
    Else
        ReDim arr(1 To WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Len(strSplit) / 256 + 1, 0))
        k = 1
Restart:
        strInterm = left(IIf(strRest = "", strSplit, strRest), 256)
        If Len(strInterm) < 256 Then boolLast = True
        If boolLast Then
            arr(k) = strInterm
            ReDim Preserve arr(k): split256 = arr
            Exit Function
        Else
            arr(k) = left(strInterm, InStrRev(strInterm, ",") - 1): k = k + 1
            strRest = Right(IIf(strRest = "", strSplit, strRest), _
                  Len(IIf(strRest = "", strSplit, strRest)) - InStrRev(strInterm, ",") - 1)
            GoTo Restart
            End If
    End If    
End Function
```

Comment: It's always fine to find such alternatives :+)

Comment: @T.M.: I only played VBA... I do no think I will ever need such a function. :)

Comment: Just tested it. Works fine. Thank you, @FaneDuru.

Comment: @Wilfred: Glad I could help! Since somebody is interested in such a function, I improved it, eliminating iteration for setting the array element length and `strRest`... You can test it.

Comment: @FaneDuru: I did already. Works fine! Am documenting it in my banks of code. Thank you.